# MLE with Model Uncertainty

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uncertainty

I am trying to estimate the amount of background in some physics data by using MLE to fit a weighted sum of a signal and background distribution to the data where the weights indicate what percentage of the real data is signal or background.

$$\theta f_{Signal} + (1 - \theta) f_{Background} $$

However, I don't really have an analytic expression for these distributions, rather the distributions are histograms that came out of a Monte Carlo simulation I ran of the system.

Because the distributions come out of a Monte Carlo simulation, I would like to account for the fact that there should be some amount of uncertainty in the number of events in every bin in the histograms when I am fitting. Ideally, I want to make sure that the fit doesn't give too much importance to histogram bins that have a very low number of events and when calculating the variance in the fitted parameter $\theta$, I also want to make sure the variance includes the uncertainty in the shapes of the $f_{Signal}$ and $f_{Background}$ distributions. What would be some good ways to modify traditional MLE to incorporate these uncertainties?

Comment: you can use weighted losses, which is common for skewed datasets... however, it seems that your response is continuous, but you are talking about bins in histogram... are you sure that you are dealing with a discrete response variable?

Comment: The response variable is technically continuous, however, I don't have an analytic expression for its PDF, all I have is the results of a Monte Carlo simulation which outputs histograms that I am taking as an approximation of the true PDF. I will look into the weighted loss, thanks for the advice.